# Can I execute a function inside a declarative macro?

Tags: rust

I'm stuck trying to "rename" a identifier inside a declarative macro, I have the renaming function already, but can't find a way to "execute" it inside the macro. Is this possible with declarative macros?

Example:

```rust
fn to_pascal_case(s: &str) -> String { ... }

macro_rules! test_gl_enum {
    ($n: ident) => { struct to_pascal_case(stringify!($n)); }
}

test_gl_enum!(VERTEX_SHADER);
```

expands to:

```rust
struct to_pascal_case(());
```

desired result would be:

```rust
struct VertexShader;
```

Comment: No, macros are evaluated at compile time, but `to_pascal_case` doesn't really exist as a function until runtime.

Comment: You can do this using procedural macros. This is done by making a separate crate that gets run at compile time to modify the token tree and make arbitrary changes to your code. A simple macro like `to_pascal_case!()` sounds very achievable. It can sound intimidating, but it isn't that difficult once you get the hang of using crates like `syn` and `quote`. https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html

Answer (score 3):

You can't execute arbitrary code in a declarative macro. You have a couple of options:

#### Proc Macro

Proc macros are basically just functions that take a `TokenStream` and return a `TokenStream` (with some variations between function-like, attribute and derive macros). They can contain arbitrary code, so you could absolutely parse the identifier and apply some transformation to it.

If you're going to take this route, you will likely want to use `syn` and `quote`, and I'd also very strongly recommend going through [the proc macro workshop](https://github.com/dtolnay/proc-macro-workshop), which is a series of exercises to teach you the basics.

#### Or use a crate

As is often the case, someone else has also had this problem, and has written a crate for it: https://crates.io/crates/casey

With that, you can write:

```rust
use casey::*;

macro_rules! test_gl_enum {
  ($n:ident) => {
    struct pascal!($n);
  };
}
```

Here, `pascal!()` is a proc macro that does the transformation, and since it's a macro (rather than a function) it is also evaluated at compile time, so the expansion won't look like `struct pascal!(my_enum_name);`